# Pre-pend required number of characters in Excel

Tags: excel, concatenation, prepend

I need to prepend field values in an Excel sheet with the required number of characters to equal 5 characters in the field, then concatenate two fields and have all of the characters show in the new field.

Example:

Field 1 |  Field 2 | Show as

abc |     123  |  00abc00123

d   |     5678 |  0000d05675

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you may want is something like:

```
=REPT(0,5-LEN(A1))&A1&REPT(0,5-LEN(B1))&B1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `TEXT` on a number field.

```
=REPT(0,5-LEN(A1))&A1&TEXT(B1,"00000")
```